# Create function in memory

Tags: c++, memory, function-pointers

I learned about function pointers recently in class and I was wondering if you could assign a function pointer to a block of memory allocated by a program, fill the memory block with assembly commands (hex values of op codes), then call the memory block using the function pointer.

I don't know much about function pointers, but I'm guessing you can't assign them wherever you want in memory, they need to point to a function. If that's true, how can you create a function in memory to be called? Is that even possible?

Here's some code I typed up to show the concept. I used various opcode values to see if anything would work, and 0x90 (NOP) did not break it sometimes (but it did other times), and 0xC3 (ret) always broke it.

```
#include <stdlib.h> //for malloc
#include <cstring> //for memcpy

int main() //program entry
{
    void(*test)() = NULL; //create function pointer, initialize to NULL
    void* hold_address = (void*)malloc(100); //allocate memory, save the address it returns in a dummy pointer
    int asm_commands[] = {0x90}; //create array of assembly commands, hex values
    memcpy(hold_address, asm_commands, sizeof(asm_commands)); //copy the array into the reserved memory
    test = (void(*)())hold_address; //set the function pointer to start of the allocated memory
    test(); //call the function, crashes here
    return 0; //exit the program
}
```

Comment: What you're referring to is called "[JITting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)". [This page](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/05/how-to-jit-an-introduction) has some good info to get you started.

Comment: @MooseBoys: no it's not... your JIT link is still about compilation - the creation of opcodes from some other source or byte-code representation, whereas this question's just about moving the pre-existing opcodes somewhere for execution and what those opcodes should be.  That said, the link may still be helpful as the functionality here is subset of what a JIT system needs to do.

Comment: @TonyD This is still JIT, it's just a special case, analogous to compiling a program composed entirely of `__asm` blocks.

Comment: @MooseBoys: it's not even vaguely like "compiling a program composed entirely of __asm" blocks as such blocks are still assembly language source code, while `asm_commands` in this program already holds machine code opcodes, besides which `__asm` blocks aren't doing JIT compilation either - they're compiled to machine code alongside the C++ code embedding them, not at runtime as for JIT; anyway, I've no particular wish for us to reach agreement - just cautioning other readers against possible misunderstanding of the term, and they can read and conclude whatever they like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points:

- your `asm_commands[]` should probably be `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) - as is, you'll be copying 3 NUL/0 characters as well as the `0x90`
- some Operating Systems will just not let you execute instructions in memory you've allocated with `malloc()` - they'll SIGSEGV or similar instead - that's intended to prevent certain types of stack overflow and other hackery
- I suggest you write an actual function `void f() { }` and see what opcodes are generated for it, using `g++ -S` or whatever your compiler offers, as you might need to do something more than just `0xC3` to return properly (e.g. pop certain registers)

  - if "cloning" instructions from an actual C++ function to get you started on a tweaked asm function, be wary of position dependent code too... you can't just copy data and code addresses within the function as they won't be inside the malloced region.  Position Independent Code (PIC) uses relative addressing opcodes to avoid this... that's what you'll need to write.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you describe. However, memory allocated with `malloc()` might not have the permission for code execution - depending on your platform.

The way to allocate executable memory differs from OS to OS. On Linux, check `mmap`. On Windows, see `VirtualAlloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Function calling is more complex than that.

You must at least modify the base pointer. I suggest you look at the dissassembly of a function call and try to mimic it