# Calling putchar address from C++

Tags: c++, assembly

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857809/create-function-in-memory), I asked if it was possible to write and execute assembly commands in memory. I got some nice responses, and after a bit more research, I figured out how to do it. Now that I can do it, I am having trouble figuring out what to write to memory (and how to do it correctly). I know some assembly and how the mnemonics translate to opcodes, but I can't figure out how to use the opcodes correctly.

Here's an example I'm trying to get working:

```
void(*test)() = NULL; //create function pointer, initialize to NULL
void* hold_address = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 5*1024, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE); //allocate memory, make writable/ readable/ executable
unsigned char asm_commands[] = {0x55, 0x89, 0xE5, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x18, 0xC7, 0x04, 0x24, 0x41, 0xE8, 0x1E, 0xB3, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC9, 0xC3}; //create array of assembly commands, hex values
memcpy(hold_address, asm_commands, sizeof(asm_commands)[0]*10); //copy the array into the reserved memory
test = (void(*)())hold_address; //set the function pointer to start of the allocated memory
test(); //call the function
```

Just placing 0xC3 into the asm_commands array works (and the function just returns), but that's boring. The series of opcodes (and addresses) I have in there right now are supposed to print out the character "A" (capital a). I got the opcodes and addresses from debugging a simple program that calls printf("A") and finding the call in memory. Right now, the program returns a 0xC00000096 error, "privileged command". I think the error stems from trying to call the system putchar address directly, which the system doesn't like. I also think I can bypass that by giving my program Ring 0 access, but I hardly know what that entails other than a lot of potential problems.

So is there any way to either call the printf() function (in assembly opcodes) without needing higher privileges?

I'm using Windows 7, 64-bit, Code::Blocks 10.05 (GNU GCC Compiler).

Here's a screenshot of the debugged printf() call (in OllyDebug):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
unsigned char asm_commands[] = {0x55, 0x89E5…
```

Whoa, hang on, stop right there. `0x89E5` isn't a valid value for an `unsigned char`, and your compiler should probably be complaining about this. (If not, check your settings; you've probably disabled some very important warnings.)

You'll need to split your code in this initializer up into individual bytes, e.g.

```
{0x55, 0x89, 0xE5, …
```

Comment: Can you split addresses apart like that? I just did what you said and it runs (without any errors), but nothing gets printed out.

You were right about the compiler complaining by the way, but I wasn't sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing gets printed out because you forgot these zeroes in the dword 0x00000041 and mistakenly wrote 0x1A in stead of 0x1E.

unsigned char asm_commands[] = {0x55, 0x89, 0xE5, 0x83, 0xEC, 0x18, 0xC7, 0x04, 0x24, 0x41, **0x00, 0x00, 0x00,** 0xE8, **0x1E,** 0xB3, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC9, 0xC3}; //create array of assembly commands, hex values

Comment: I didn't notice the 0x1E, thank you. It didn't fix the problem however.

I did notice the 0x00's, and when I add them in, I get the 0xC0000005 error (some amount of 0's in there), which _I think_ is the "bad pointer deference" error (which I'm guessing means the commands I wrote break it).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @duskwuff and @user3144770 wrote. Did you change the following line to include *every* byte?

```
memcpy(hold_address, asm_commands, sizeof(asm_commands)[0]*10);
```

I have counted 20 bytes of assembly code!

```
memcpy(hold_address, asm_commands, sizeof(asm_commands)[0]*20);
```

Comment: I made sure to change the amount being copied, still doesn't work :/