# Not allowed to call putchar address

Tags: c++, assembly

Continuing again an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336948/calling-putchar-address-from-c/28383384), I am having trouble calling the Windows 7 putchar address manually.

I use an array of assembly opcodes to emulate a C++ function and a call to the printf() command. I copy the array of opcodes into reserved memory and call it using a function pointer that I point to the start of the array (after being copied into memory).

The array(s) in question:

```
uint8_t asmCommandsPart1[] = {0x55, //push EBP
                              0x89, 0xE5, //mov EBP, ESP
                              0x83, 0xEC, 0x18, //sub ESP, 0x18
                              0xC7, 0x04, 0x24, 0x41, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //mov DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],0x41
                              0xE8}; //call
                              //The next byte is the start of the offset to jump to

uint8_t asmCommandsPart2[] = {0xC9, 0xC3}; //leave, retn
```

I calculate the jump offset by using a constant address and subtracting the address of the last byte of asmCommandsPart1 (0xE8) from that address, and adding 5. I can confirm that this works, because I printed out the byte values at the calculated address (address of 0xE8 in asmCommandsPart1 + offset) and compared them to the values in a disassembled version of the program (done in OllyDbg) and they matched.

Here's how I calculate the offset, along with the memcpy calls placing the address in memory (hold_address is a pointer to the start of the reserved memory):

```
memcpy(hold_address, asmCommandsPart1, sizeof(asmCommandsPart1)[0]*14); //copy the array into the reserved memory
int asmCommandsOffset = 14; //when calculating offset when counting in array, start at 0
char* jumpFromAddress = (hold_address+asmCommandsOffset); //Calculate the end of asmCommandsPart1 starting from hold_address
char* jumpToAddress = reinterpret_cast<char*>(0x0041CA70); //Create pointer to memory where jumping to
int jumpAddressOffset = abs((int)(jumpToAddress-jumpFromAddress))+5; //Calculate the offset between the two pointers
memcpy(jumpFromAddress, &jumpAddressOffset, sizeof(jumpAddressOffset)); //copy calculated address of putchar into memory
memcpy(jumpFromAddress+sizeof(jumpAddressOffset), asmCommandsPart2, sizeof(asmCommandsPart2)[0]*2); //copy 0xC9 and 0xC3 into memory
```

The only problem is the program returns a 0x3 error when jumping to the putchar address. The MSDN docs on [NTSTATUS values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) tells me this is a "STATUS_WAIT_3" error code, but that and the description of it tell me nothing. The MSDN docs on [System Error Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say that it is a ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND error, which again, tells me nothing.

What am I missing? The address is obviously callable, the program already does it, I just cannot replicate it, even when copying the opcodes exactly (note: the opcodes/ order of have never changed, just the addresses).

Note that jumping to a nearby address, such as abort, works fine. I have only tested abort and putchar though. Also note that I realize the address of the putchar changes, I will work on calculating it dynamically next.

Here's a picture of the putchar and abort commands in memory. Jumping to 0041CA80 will cause the program to crash with error code 0x3, jumping to 0041CA90 will work fine.

[image]

Comment: It's not necessarily a function. In most implementations it's a macro, *ergo* it doesn't have an address you can take.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding you, but the screenshot I provided shows the address I can jump to, no? And how come I can jump to abort but not putchar?